# Laravel refresh page and go to the correct tab after inserting record

Tags: jquery, laravel, tabs

I have a bootstrap datatable inside a modal.
When I click a button in this datatable a new record is inserted into the DB, the modal closes automatically but in the parent windows I don't see the new record. When I put location.reload in my success ajax response the record is ok, but the page reload and goes to the active tab which is not correct. I tried location.hash = '#tab2'; but nothing changed.

This is my JS function:

```
function addMemberToLessonDirect(id)
    {
        console.log(id);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
            url: '/admin/lessons/addMember/licenseMemberId', // This is the url we gave in the route
            data: {'licenseMemberId' : id},
            success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                console.log(response);
                //location.hash = '#tab2';
                location.reload();
            }
           
        });

    }
```

The table is generated with Yajra Datatables:

```
public function getMembersDirect()
{
    $members = DB::table('members')
        ->select(['license_member.id as id','nip','firstname','lastname', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, "%d-%m-%Y") as birthdate'),'description'])
        ->join('license_member','members.id','license_member.member_id')
        ->join ('licenses','licenses.id','license_member.license_id')

        ->whereNull('members.deleted_at')
        ->orderBy('members.lastname','asc');


    return Datatables::of($members)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('action', function ($member) {


            $clic="addMemberToLessonDirect($member->id)";
            $link='<a onclick="'.$clic.'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" title="Add to lesson"></i></a>';
            return $link;})->make(true);

}
```

And this is the part of my blade file with 2 tabs (I want that it refresh on tab 2):

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabMenu">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">{{__('lesson.detail')}}</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">{{__('lesson.members')}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('lessons.update', ['lesson' => $id]) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa"></i> {{__('lesson.update')}}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="actual-members">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" ># {{__('member.id')}}</th>
                    <th scope="row" >{{__('member.firstname')}}</th>  
                    <th scope="row" ></th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($lesson->LessonLicenseMember as $llm)
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row" >{{$llm->licenseMember->member->id}}</td>
                    <td scope="row" >{{$llm->licenseMember->member->firstname}}</td>
                    <td scope="row" >{{$llm->licenseMember->member->lastname}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form class="delete" action="{{ route('lessons.removeMember', ['licenseMemberId' => $llm->id]) }}" method="POST">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete" >
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="{{__('lesson.remove_member_from_lesson')}}"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
            <a href="{{ route('lessons.index',['type'=>$lesson->course->type->description]) }}#{{$lesson->course->id}}"class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>{{__('general.back')}}</a>&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#membersModal">
                {{__('lesson.addMember')}}
            </button>
            <div class="panel-body" id="allMembers" style="display: none;">   
                <h6><b>{{__('member.list')}}</b></h6>
                {{-- @include('admin.lessons.lessons_members_direct') --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried using both together on one of my single page apps, and worked okay:

```
  // first change the url
  location.hash = '#tab2'; // or location.href = "#tab2"
  // then refresh
  location.reload();
```

But the problem that you have is because you always have the first tab as active, this should change.

In order to display new records when you use ajax, unless you use model view binding frameworks such as Vue or Angular, you will always need to manually append the new record in your ajax success callback.

Or if you go by reloading the page, your active tab should change based on the result.
You can trigger a change on the active tab using jquery as follows:

```
$('a[href="#tab2"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Itryied your second solution, the trigger  $('a[href="#tab2"]').trigger('click'); has effect only if I don't write location.reload();, if I reload the page goes to the first tab. If I remove the reload the trigger the modal don't close and the parent page doesn't reload the content.